# How to query for both posts and post upvotes in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am attempting to model post upvotes and posts in MySQL. Currently I have an elements table for posts and a likes table for upvotes, structured as follows.

**likes** (*id, elementID, googleID*)

**elements** (*id, googleID, title, body, type*)

I have a URL route that will either return the most recent posts, or the posts with the most upvotes depending on a parameter. I want to query for a set of posts, each listing how many upvotes they have. The website won't display who upvoted, but the database should keep track of this to prevent multiple upvotes.

I tried to do something such as:

```
SELECT elements.id, elements.googleID, elements.title, likes.id, likes.elementID
FROM elements
INNER JOIN likes
ON elements.id=likes.elementID
```

This did not work well.

How would I get a set of posts, each showing how many upvotes they have when the upvotes are stored in a separate table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to query for a set of posts, each listing how many upvotes
>   they have.

You can try this query. I used `LEFT JOIN` so you can still get the posts without likes.

```
SELECT E.id
    , E.googleID
    , E.title
    , L.likeCount
    FROM elements E
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT elementId
            , COUNT(id) AS likeCount
            FROM likes
            GROUP BY elementId
    ) L ON L.elementId = E.id
```

Or (not pretty sure if this will run properly in `MySQL`)

```
SELECT E.id
    , E.googleID
    , E.title
    , COUNT(L.id)
    FROM elements E
    LEFT JOIN likes L ON L.elementID = E.id
    GROUP BY E.id
```

> The website won't display who upvoted, but the database should keep
>   track of this to prevent multiple upvotes

You can create a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` in your `LIKES` table, for `elementID` and `googleID` columns. This will make sure that a `googleID` can only like one `elementID`. Otherwise, it will throw a unique constraint violation.

With that, when a user is upvoting a post, you can check in the database first if the user has already an existing record in the `LIKES` table before inserting one.

Comment: This works, thanks a ton! But the select inside of the join is foreign to me. I sort of understand that, but barely and would not be able to come up with something like that on my own. Is it doing another query for each row in the elements table? I'll also have to look into what left join means. I still have a lot to learn, I guess.

Comment: I'm using `TSQL` for now. And it doesn't allow me to access columns which are not included in the `GROUP BY` clause, which is why I used `SUBQUERY`. I haven't used mysql for 2 years, but just in case, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I recall learning about subqueries in my short database course, I am just new to SQL/MySQL as a whole. Your answer worked the way it was, I was just wondering.

Comment: AFAIK, the subquery is executed only once, because we placed it in `JOIN`. Most of the time, subqueries are inefficient if we placed them in the `WHERE` clause. You might want to take a look at this: http://www.chrislondon.co/joins-vs-subqueries/